# Does Apache Spark MLlib 1.3.1 correctly compute multi-class precision and recall values?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

Just tried the MulticlassMetrics feature in Spark MLlib 1.3.1 with a simple generic (label,predicition) input

```
(label, predicition)
( 1.0 , 1.0)
( 2.0 , 2.0)
( 3.0 , 3.0)
( 4.0 , 3.0)
( 4.0 , 4.0)
( 4.0 , 4.0)
```

and I get ( Scala code snippet shown )

```
    labelsAndPredictions.foreach(println)

    val metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(labelsAndPredictions)
    println("confusionMatrix: ")        
    println(metrics.confusionMatrix)

    println("Precision: ")
    metrics.labels.foreach( x => println(x.toInt + " " + metrics.precision(x.toInt)) )

    println("Recall: ")
    metrics.labels.foreach( x => println(x.toInt + " " + metrics.recall(x.toInt)) )
```

the precision result values

precision:

```
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   0.6666666666666666
```

which seems to be at odds with what one would expect:

```
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   0.5
4   1.0
```

**Precision:** *Given all the predicted labels (for a given class X), how many instances were correctly predicted?* ( see more at: http://www.text-analytics101.com/2014/10/computing-precision-and-recall-for.html#sthash.OTmBn0Vb.dpuf)

So for class label 4 I would expect

```
prec(4) = 1.0 (2 out of 2 are correct)
```

and for class label 3 I would expect

```
prec(3) = 0.5 (1 out of 2 are correct).
```

If I call MLlib recall() on the same data set, I get the expected (correct) result for precision.

Could it be that precision() and recall() in MLlib are currently incorrectly interchanged?

Any input,comment would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: latest version is 1.4.1 so maybe you can try and see what happens there

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `MulticlassMetrics` expects `predictionAndLabels`, an RDD of `(prediction, label)` pairs. You've got it the other way around, which is why the precision and recall are flipped.

See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics